# ListView in horizontal StackLayout - Nativescript Vue

Tags: listview, nativescript, nativescript-vue, stacklayout

I'm new on Nativescript with Vue and I'm trying to display a list of items with ListView in a StackLayout with horizontal orientation.

What I expect is that the three elements that the ListView will cycle, will be showed on the same line thanks to the StackLayout.

Instead, the three elements are displayed on separate lines.

See this playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=cHwk9f

How can i display all the items on the same line (as buttons)?

Thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` currently don't support horizontal orientation.

You could use `RadListView` if you still want a `ListView` behavior, especially if you have a lot of items that you want to display.

```bash
ns plugin add nativescript-ui-listview
```

```html
 <RadListView scrollOrientation="horizontal">
  ...
</RadListView>
```

More on that [here](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/radlistview/getting-started)

If you don't have a lot of items that you want to display inside the `ListView`, you could alternatively go for a `ScrollView` and a `StackLayout`:

```html
<ScrollView orientation="horizontal">
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
     <!-- your item templates goes here maybe in a v-for -->
  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you, the RadListView component it turned out to be perfect